# Tensorflow how pooling layer is connected to convolutional layer

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Is there a way to selectively connect the feature maps of a pooling layer to the feature maps of a (sequential) convolutional layer?
In the paper "Gradient-Based Learning Applied To Document Recognition" [Proc. of the IEEE, Nov 1998] LeCun et al. describe how a subsampling layer is selectively connected to a subsequent convolutional layer.
In the basic TF example (A guide to TF layers: Building a CNN) conv2 is connected to pool1 as:

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, ...

however, I'd like to selectively connect pool1 to conv2 in a similar way the LeCun paper connects S2 to C3 (see Table 1).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't examined this paper. Just want to share that you can [manipulate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops) your `pool1` tensor any way your like before passing it to the `conv2d` layer, e.g. split it by two and connect each one to its own conv layer.

For instance, that's what [LSTM cell](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) is doing (see the implementation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/37f7ad75bbd2ca140d1092342eb3590d54193bc8/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L344)).